# Type safety of input.nextLine?

Tags: java, console-application, user-input, java.util.scanner, type-safety

Would there ever be a case where an exception could be thrown by assigning the value of `input.nextLine()` to a `String` variable with the `Scanner`?

Like if you put

```
String foo = input.nextInt();
```

You would get an `InputMismatchException`. So what I'm wondering is if there's any possible way to get an exception from:

```
String foo = input.nextLine();
```

It might be a dumb question but I need to be absolutely sure.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are we talking about `Scanner` ?

Comment: Yes sorry...will edit now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29):

> Throws: 
> **NoSuchElementException** - if no line was found
>   **IllegalStateException** - if this scanner is closed

Tip for easier and safer life: Always refer to the docs.

Comment: What would be a circumstance in which no line would be found? For example, when I run a program that asks the user for input, if I ONLY press return and nothing else, it doesn't crash. So if the user is being asked for input, what would he press in order for a line to not be found?

Comment: @Justin Assuming no other bugs, I think Ctrl + D will do the trick.

Comment: @DennisMeng: Thank you, that is the kind of thing I was looking for; learned something new!